# Can we render only a small part of CALayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, calayer

I want to check the alpha value of a point in CALayer. For that rendering, the complete layer is way too expensive for me. Is there a way I can render only a small needed part of the CAlayer around the point of the question?

**Code:**

```c
(BOOL) transparentPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGFloat alpha = pixel[3]/255.0;
    BOOL transparent = alpha < 0.01;
    return transparent;
}
```

Comment: You could break up your layer in multiple sublayers. Then only check the sublayer that has the point.

Comment: I may suggest you look at CATailedLayer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catiledlayer
Haven't worked with it yet, but according to documentation there is a possibility to render only small part of a layer